# Disable one section of the page with radio buttons in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have three radio buttons, I want to gray out a section of the page when selecting a specific radio button while the other two should remove the gray out rules of the previous radio

`input[name='retirementOptions']` is targeting all three radios this is working fine, while `"input[type=radio]#PhasedRetirement"` target the specific section but the `else statement` is not working

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let optionsBoxGuaranteeCheckbox = document.querySelector(".options-box--checkbox");
  let guaranteedAnnuity = document.getElementById("GuaranteedAnnuity");

  $("input[name='retirementOptions']").change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      guaranteedAnnuity.removeAttribute("disabled");
    }
  });

  $("input[type=radio]#PhasedRetirement").change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $(guaranteedAnnuity).attr("disabled");
      $(optionsBoxGuaranteeCheckbox).css({
        "opacity": ".7",
        "background-color": "#F3F5F7"
      });
      $(optionsBoxGuaranteeCheckbox).addClass('options-box-unchecked');
    } else {
      $(optionsBoxGuaranteeCheckbox).removeClass('options-box-unchecked');
      $(optionsBoxGuaranteeCheckbox).css({
        "opacity": "1",
        "background-color": "transparent"
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="options-box">
  <input type="radio" name="retirementOptions" class="checkbox-default-custom" id="ExtendedRangeLivingAnnuity" value="Extended Range Living Annuity">
</div>
<div class="options-box">
  <input type="radio" name="retirementOptions" class="checkbox-default-custom" id="PhasedRetirement" value="Phased Retirement">
</div>
<div class="options-box options-box--checkbox">
  <input type="radio" class="checkbox-default-custom" id="GuaranteedAnnuity" value="Guaranteed Annuity">
</div>
```

I want this section to apply the style

```
<div class="options-box options-box--checkbox">
 <p class="body-text-b3 no-bottom-margin">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus luctus rutrum justo non mattis.
 </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please click [edit] then the button shaped like `[<>]` and provide a [mcve] with relevant HTML, CSS and Script

Comment: Just by giving us the selector does not give us ANY idea of your HTML - do you have duplicate IDs for example

Comment: Also use  toggleClass and booleans: `guaranteedAnnuity.attr("disabled",!this.checked);` and `$(optionsBoxGuaranteeCheckbox).toggleClass('options-box-unchecked',this.checked);` and put the CSS in the stylesheet

Comment: And if you cache the elements, use jQuery:  `const $guaranteedAnnuity = $("#GuaranteedAnnuity");` and then later `$guaranteedAnnuity.attr("disabled",this.checked);`

Comment: Please update the snippet I made with relevant CSS so it is a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a go with this.

```js
$(function() {
  const $optionsBoxGuaranteeCheckbox = $(".options-box--checkbox");
  const $guaranteedAnnuity = $("#GuaranteedAnnuity");

  $("input[name='retirementOptions']").on("click", function() {
    $guaranteedAnnuity.prop("disabled", this.checked);
  });

  $("#PhasedRetirement").on("click", function() {
    dis(this.checked)
  });

  const dis = chk => {
    $guaranteedAnnuity.prop("disabled", !chk);
    $optionsBoxGuaranteeCheckbox.toggleClass('options-box-unchecked', !chk);
  };
  dis($("#PhasedRetirement").is(":checked")); // initialise
});
```

```css
.options-box--checkbox {
  "opacity": ".7", "background-color": "#F3F5F7"
}

.options-box-unchecked {
  "opacity": "1", "background-color": "transparent"
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="options-box">
  <input type="radio" name="retirementOptions" class="checkbox-default-custom" id="ExtendedRangeLivingAnnuity" value="Extended Range Living Annuity">
</div>
<div class="options-box">
  <input type="radio" name="retirementOptions" class="checkbox-default-custom" id="PhasedRetirement" value="Phased Retirement">
</div>
<div class="options-box options-box--checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-default-custom" id="GuaranteedAnnuity" value="Guaranteed Annuity">
</div>
```